# Какой разделитель использовать для объединения бинарных файлов?

Tags: python

Вопрос состоит из двух частей:

1. Абстрактный вопрос
2. Конкретный вопрос

Если на первый не будет ответа, то прошу ответить на второй.

1. У нас есть 2 файла, которые состоят из битов, биты эти никакими форматами не ограничены. Какой разделитель лучше использовать для объединения двух битовых файлов в один, с учетом того , что я не хочу увидеть этот разделитель в данных одного из двух представленных файлов? И есть ли какой-нибудь договор относительно этого момента в среде разработки ake последовательность "aaaaabbbb" в наши данные мы не вставляем.
2. Какой разделитель лучше использовать для объединения двух .ttf файлов в один файл?

Comment: 1 - Никакой. Добавляйте "Содержание" в начале своего "архива" (например с записями вида `имя - смещение`).  2 - см п.1.

Comment: Ну либо надо точно знать, каких последовательностей точно не может быть в данных. Но так то да, каталог в начале файла - самый лучший способ.

Comment: Непонятна цель этих «усовершенствований»?

Comment: Я бы использовал MD5 (128 бит, т.е. 16 байт) или SHA-1 (160 бит, 20 байт) от первых нескольких байт (можно начать с одного байта) первого файла. Вычислил, и проверил, что такой последовательности в файле нет. Если есть, (практически не вероятно) то добавил следующий байт, вычислил и проверил и т.д. В конце-концов получим нужный разделитель и добавим к нему длину последовательности, использованной для вычисления. Все. Разделитель готов. Программа, разбирающая такой файл вычисляет разделитель по тому же алгоритму, находит его и делит файл на 2 исходных. Так же можно склеивать и несколько файлов

Comment: ````FormData````